# Unexpected tag <target> in top-level of build file in Jenkins build

Tags: ant, jenkins, drupal-7, phing

I have Jenkins 1.624 to automate a build for Drupal 7. Below are the details required:

```
Git Version: 1.9.1
Apache Ant Version: 1.9.6
Jenkins Version: 1.624
Drupal Version: 7.X
```

Whenever I 'build now', it starts to build but fails with the below mentioned error log:

> /var/www/project/build/build.xml:57:15: /var/www/project/build/build.components/build.documentation.xml:7:38: Unexpected tag  in top-level of build file.

I am very new to Jenkins. Please help.

Comment: this likely has little to do with jenkins... does your build file work locally?

Comment: If you mean the local project setup, its working fine. The error occurs when I try to create a build using jenkins UI. 
I am not sure if this is the solution but when I used all the build components inline it worked. Earlier I was using import statement for all build components.

Comment: The error message `Unexpected tag in top-level of build file` comes from [Phing](http://www.phing.info/trac/browser/classes/phing/parser/RootHandler.php?rev=0583028cb27386e85943fe8e4636917fd6e416dd), not Ant. Is Jenkins using Phing while you use Ant locally?

Comment: Yes Jenkins using Phing while I Ant locally. The issue was coming when I was using the import tag in the build.xml. I updated the build.xml with not using the import tags and putting inline the XML of all the required components.
I am not sure if this is the right way of resolving this issue. But atleast it worked for me.
I am still looking forward to a more structured and standard option of resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the tag `target` not working outside the tag `project`
The solution is add the tag `project` for each file and call `project:target`